# BAD ACCESS on nil Check

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash

I'm pretty stumped on why this is crashing.  It's an NSTimer property that's being released and then checking for nil is leading to a crash.  Doesn't make sense.

Original:

```
if (self.adCountdown != nil) {
    if ([self.adCountdown isValid]) {
        [self.adCountdown invalidate];
        self.adCountdown = nil;
    }
}
```

Crashed on self.adCountdown = nil;

Changed to:

```
if (self.adCountdown != nil) {
    if ([self.adCountdown isValid]) {
        [self.adCountdown invalidate];
    }
}
if (self.adCountdown != nil) {
    self.adCountdown = nil;
}
```

Now crashes on:
if (self.adCountdown != nil)

This is a property built as:
@property (nonatomic, retain)
No ARC.

This is a rare crash and only occasionally happens.  I've never known an nil check to crash.

EDIT: ADDED FULL BACKTRACE
[image: Crash Backtrace]

[image: viewWillDisappear]

James

Comment: why do u use retain attribute in your property ?

Comment: there is nothing wrong with your code. do u get any other crash reason ?

Comment: there is a chance that after timer is nil, it is accessed at some point on ur code!!! Can u post the whole code ?

Comment: Does `[self.adCountdown invalidate]` do anything crazy? is there a custom setter/getter defined for it? Try just accessing self.adCountdown, like literally `self.adCountdown;` after calling invalidate and seeing what happens. edit: yeah, please post the rest of the code that touches `self.adCountdown`

Comment: If it only occasionally happens, it's not crashing because of the nil check.  What about the object itself (`self`)?  Could it have been `dealloc`ed already?

Comment: I use retain because it's not ARC.  The crash is at this point in the code just after checking if it is nil and invalidating.  No custom getter/setter (standard synthesized).

Comment: This code is wrapped in a "stopCountdown" method that runs on viewWillDisappear.  I can't imagine self getting deallocated until [super dealloc] which is the last line in dealloc.  Other properties aren't crashing, just this one.

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty clearly an over-release.   The `self.adCountdown` could easily crash if `self` is already deallocated.   If the last `retain` of self was because it was the target of the timer, then `[self.adCountdown invalidate]` could cause `self` to be `release`d and, thus, deallocated.

Comment: I would expect to see dealloc run if self was released and the crash would be in dealloc where I also have self.adCountdown = nil as well.

Comment: @JamesR.Cahall Without seeing more context, hard to say.   I wouldn't expect to see the crash in -dealloc because, when -dealloc is running, self is still viable for property setting.   I *suspect* it is the method invocation on an over-released `self` that is causing the issue, based on the evidence at hand.   What does the backtrace say?

Comment: Added backtrace.  viewWillDisappear calls this stopCountdown function.